# ruby for loop to generate matrix

Tags: ruby, matrix

I have this for loop:

```
 for i in 0...4
  for j in 0...4
      puts "#{i}:#{j}"
  end
end
```

outputs:

```
0:0
0:1
0:2
0:3
1:0
1:1
1:2
1:3
2:0
2:1
2:2
2:3
3:0
3:1
3:2
3:3
```

but I like to generate a matrix of this result.  I need to put all 0: in one line and all 1: in one line etc to generate this:

```
0:0 0:1 0:2 0:3
1:0 1:1 1:2 1:3
2:0 2:1 2:2 2:3
3:0 3:1 3:2 3:3
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the documentation, [**puts**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-puts) "writes a record separator (typically a newline) after any that do not already end with a newline sequence". So you need to use [**print**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-print) instead (but still use `puts` to move to a new line when each row is done printing)

```
for i in 0...4
  for j in 0...4
      print "#{i}:#{j} "
  end
  puts
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
matrix = (0..3).to_a.repeated_permutation(2).each_slice(4)
print matrix.map{|row| row.map{|column| column.join(":")}.join(" ")}.join("\n")
```

Comment: +1, but no need for a one-liners, split it (two lines?) and you'll get a nice and clear functional approach. Also, `map` is shorter. Also, I'd use plural variables names for collections.

Comment: I think you mean `(0...4).to_a.repeated_permutation`